# Is there module-esound-protocol-tcp on 19.10

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I'm trying to share my audio to other hosts on LAN using `paprefs`
But after setting option "Enable network access to local sound devices" I get syslog error

```
ltdl-bind-now.c: Failed to open module module-esound-protocol-tcp.so: module-esound-protocol-tcp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
module.c: Failed to open module "module-esound-protocol-tcp".
```

Is there any possibility how to install `module-esound-protocol-tcp` on Ubuntu 19.10?

Answer (score 0):

In previous Ubuntu versions this file was a part of `pulseaudio-esound-compat` package ([up-to 18.04 LTS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=module-esound-protocol-tcp)). The source code base for it is [`pulseaudio`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/pulseaudio-esound-compat).

You have to open `software-properties-gtk` and enable *Source Code* here first.

Then you have to get all necessary build-dependencies with `sudo apt-get build-dep pulseaudio`.

Then get the source package:

```
cd ~/Downloads
apt-get source pulseaudio
```

And then configure the source code with `--enable-esound` and compile new version of package.

But better way is to simply reinstall Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and use it for another 3 years.

Comment: Thanks, so it may be that the `paprefs` are obsolete or they are using not actual congfiguration of `pulseaudio` and they should use `module-native-protocol-tcp` instead?
I think the `esound` was used for better performance. But if `native` is upgraded maybe `esound` has no purpose any more.

Comment: @Athlo, I do not know technical details about all this. Investigated only on file-package level. You have to read some documentation like https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Music_Player_Daemon/Tips_and_tricks#Local_(with_separate_mpd_user) .